# Creating Data to Run with VRP WebExample

Tags: optaplanner

Is there a way to build the file with my own test data to run in the VRP webexample?

I have been able to run the data from Belgium but want to use my own data.

Answer (score 0):

We'll be adding example code for that in optaplanner-webexamples in a future version. It will demonstrate both Google Maps and Graphhopper (OpenStreetMap).

Meanwhile, you can find the **very dirty code** that generated the Belgium road datasets [here](https://github.com/ge0ffrey/vrp-dataset-generator).